# $k$-Zariski topology. $\overline{W} = Z(I(W))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> Let $W$ be a subset of $C^{n}$. If $\overline{W}$ is the closure of $W$ in the $k$-Zariski topology on $C^{n}$, show that $\overline{W} = Z(I(W))$.

I know that $Z(I(W))$ is closed, so $\overline{W} \subseteq Z(I(W))$, since $W \subset C^{n}$. How to do the converse?

$Z$ is zero; $I$ is an ideal of $W$.

If necessary, I can write the book definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $J$ is an ideal, then $Z(I(Z(J))) = Z(J)$.  It's better to carefully write out what this is saying and convince yourself that it is true, than to bother reading a proof of this.

Since $\overline{W}$ is closed, we can write $\overline{W} = Z(J)$ for some ideal $J$.  Since $W \subseteq Z(J)$, we have $I(Z(J)) \subseteq I(W)$, hence $Z(I(W)) \subseteq Z(I(Z(J))) = Z(J) = \overline{W}$.

Comment: Nice proof! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see this more clearly in an abstract way:https://math.liveadvances.com/c-ding/if-sigma-is-a-reverse-mapping-such-that-sigma2geq-operatornameid-then-sigma3sigma/
Note that  Z,I satisfy the conditions of Proposition.

For any closed set $Z(J)\supset W$,$W\subset Z(I(W))\subset Z(I(Z(J)))=Z(J)$. This means precisely that $Z(I(W))$ is the smallest closed set that contains $W$.